# Create and Download PPTX file from Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, apache-poi

I am creating a feature where users can download a powerpoint (pptx) file constructed dynamically in the controller.

Here is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download/ppt/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint")
    public void createPPT(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable final int id) throws IOException {
        logger.debug("Get request for generating powerpoint for # " + id);

        //Create a new presentation
        XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
        //Retrieve the XSLFSlideMaster that holds layouts
        XSLFSlideMaster defaultMaster = ppt.getSlideMasters().get(0);
        //Retrieve the XSLFSlideLayout and create the new slide
        XSLFSlideLayout layout = defaultMaster.getLayout(SlideLayout.TITLE_AND_CONTENT);
        XSLFSlide slide = ppt.createSlide(layout);
        
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        ppt.write(os);
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"powerpoint.pptx\"");
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    }
```

When I hit the controller in the browser, it sends me a stream of bytes which is printed on the browser.
I was expecting a file to be downloaded.
Is there something that I am missing?

**UPDATE:**
I updated the content type to "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", but the scenario did not change.

Answer (score 0):

from what I can see you are using the content type for ppt and not for pptx.

The correct content type for pptx is:

"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"

[Office 2007 File Format MIME Types for HTTP Content Streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/hr-hr/archive/blogs/vsofficedeveloper/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2)

Comment: I updated the content type but it is still printing the bytes on the screen instead of downloading the file.